# How to upload to organizations with gpg key?

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I have GPG key and an Organization name. 
I am using Android Studio.

How can I upload the GPG key and gradle Bintray plugin?

```
bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")
}
```

Comment: It is an API Key. not gpg key.

Comment: Try looking at the documentation, if you fail, post what you have tried, and what did not work.
https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin

Comment: @gba it's work great!